# Magento2 does not load completely on windows(XAMPP)

Tags: magento2, xampp

I have installed magento2 on windows 10 machine using XAMPP. I am able to access the front end but when opens admin page it does not load successfully thus I cannot access the left side menu items(for example, magento2 does not respond when I click catalog, content etc).

[image]

I found following error message on chrome debugger panel

[image]

Comment: Please add any screenshots for your error.

Comment: @SaravananDS please have a look at the updates question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is because Magento uses `Symlink` by default to load the static files.

Open **app\etc\di.xml** and change the following line

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

To

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

Also make sure that **pub** and **pub/static** have the default .htaccess files present

Comment: Yes. It worked partially I believe 'cause  the messy page is no longer exists but the functionality is not working

Comment: Are you still getting console errors?

Comment: it works now....

Answer (score 0):

Open Xampp **Shell**,

Go to your Magento root Installtion directory and execute below Commands.

1). **`php bin/magento s:up`**

2). **`php bin/magento s:s:d`** // If your M2 version is 2.2.x than add -f like **`php bin/magento s:s:d -f`**

3). **`php bin/magento c:c`**

Check now, M2 will run as expected.